# How to remove the cancel button of SearchBar in Android?

Tags: android, maui

I am making an Android app. I am using .NET Maui for my app. I have a `SearchBar` in my app. I tried to use custom control to modify the `SearchBar`. However, I failed to do so. How do I use custom control to modify the `SearchBar`?

Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Please read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to explain properly where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/) to achieve it:

```cs
void ModifySearchBar()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            var close_btn_view = (handler.PlatformView as SearchView).FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_close_btn);
            ((ViewGroup)close_btn_view.Parent).RemoveView(close_btn_view);
#endif
        });
    }
```

For more info, you can see my pervious answer: [For android, there is space in cancel button from right side. how can i remove that?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75946099/19902734)

Comment: That case is to remove the space, not cancel button.

Comment: @EdwardYang Yes, you are right. I mean my answer of that case contain the method of how to remove the cancel button.

Comment: Ok, I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
    {
#if ANDROID
        var close_btn_view = (handler.PlatformView as AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.SearchView).FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_close_btn);
        ((Android.Views.ViewGroup)close_btn_view.Parent).RemoveView(close_btn_view);
#endif
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).